# NGINX - Extract Distinguished Name from a certificate inside a HTTP header

Tags: nginx, certificate

I have this Web infrastructure:

Clients ---> External Anti-DDOS service (reverse Proxy) ---> NGINX (Reverse Proxy) ---> PHP APP (Apache)

Clients are using 'client certificates' in this way:
1-Client starts a HTTPS conection sending his 'client certificate'
2-Anti-DDOS provider adds the 'client certicate' (full) to a HTTP header in base64 format.
3-NGINX forwards the header to  final server where php app reads the client certificate, decodes it and extact the Distinguished Name (DN) field.

I would like to extract the Distinguished Name (DN)  directly in the Nginx , to avoid send the full certificate to the final server.

Does anyone know how I can do this? I'm thinking in a Lua script, but i'm not sure that this is best way.